# Laravel 5.6 saving each step of a multi-step form in the database and local drive

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I am trying to use JQuery Steps multi-step form in Laravel 5.6.   However, instead of just saving everything in the end, I would like save every step of the form in mysql database as well as on user's local drive so that 1.  I can see where the form abandonment is happening and 2.  if user comes back they can start from where they left off.  Any tips?

http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples

Answer (score 0):

You can tap into the onChanged event and fire an asynchronous http post request with your data. You don't have to wait for the request to finish to serve the next step, it should be fully asynchronous.

See their documentation for more information
https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/wiki/Settings